# Is it possible that matrix multiplication can be performed in $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ operations but not $O(n^2)$?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, analysis-of-algorithms

The [Wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication) on the computational complexity of matrix multiplication shows that the fastest known algorithms have gone from $O(n^{2.8074})$ in 1969 to $O(n^{2.37188})$ in 2022. I wonder if the following situation is possible: **Could matrix multiplication be performed in $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ operations for all $\epsilon>0$ (using possibly different algorithms for different values of $\epsilon$), but not solved in $O(n^2)$ operations by any algorithm?**

I know little about computational complexity apart from the basic definitions, so I don't know whether there is any theorem or intuition that would show this to be impossible. It would be quite interesting if true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example, it is known that for sorting of $n$ items, one needs to do '' $c n \log n$ '' comparison instructions, where 1. I do not remember the constant $c$ $\ $ 2. I do not remember the proper rounding for $n$ that is not a power of two (and therefore I use the quatation marks, my appologies).

Likewise, there are tasks for which the best algorithm has complexity $c n^2 \log n$. This is strictly worse than $O(n^2)$ but it is $O(n^{2+\varepsilon})$ for every $\varepsilon >0$. (One algorithm for every $\varepsilon$ is actually possible.)

But we do not talk here about matrix multiplication, because the question of matrix multiplication is an open problem. The possibilities questions in math should be asked a different way, mathematics does not know about subjective possibilities.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered $O(cn^2\log n)$! I guess the even more interesting situation would be if there were no algorithm that was simultaneously $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0,$ but still an algorithm for each value $\epsilon$.

Comment: By "is it possible" I meant: "have we proven it impossible?"

Comment: For each $\varepsilon$, let $A_\varepsilon$ be an algorithm that runs less then $C_\varepsilon n^{2+\varepsilon}$ steps. Let $N_1=1$. Inductively construct $N_k$ such that $N_k > N_{k-1}$ and  for all $n \ge N_k$ we have $C_{1/k} n^{2+1/k} \le C_{1/(k-1)} n^{2+1/(k-1)}$.  

Algorithm B:  begin  Let $n$ be size of data. Find $k=k(n)$ such that $N_k\le n < N_{k+1}$. Apply algorithm $A_{1/k}$ to the data   end.

Does this work? I admit that this needs a low complexity algorithm to evaluate $k(n)$. This all should be well described in computer science, including the subtleties.  Have a link??

Comment: Or possibly this, but this may fails. Let $f(n)$ be a function that grows to $\infty$ but is $o(n^{\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon$. Algorithm C: `begin;  $n$=datasize;  start in parallel  algorithms $A_{1/k}$, $k=1...f(n)$; end`. They ran $f(n)$ times slower, the first one finished provides the answer. Does it work? What is the complexity of Algo C?